# Refreshing GridView items

Tags: android, gridview

I am working on an Android app that has one activity and five fragments.

On one of the fragments there is a GridView populated from a remote database.

I am trying to understand the behaviour of the GridView, but without success.

Just after a new app launch, the items are shown as expected. But later, if I change the database rows, adding, removing or updating them, the gridview is not updated.

As last solution, I have included a button to refresh the gridview items, but also no succes.

This the method to get the remote items:

```
   private void getUpicksFromDB(int id) {


        upicks.clear();


        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... addressesIds) {
                //  Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "UID REGISTRADO ANTES DE CARGAR REECYCLER: " + user_id);



                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://.../upicks_todos.php")
                        .build();
                try {
                    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    Log.d("aNTES","EN ONCREATE  4.5 numero de objetos "+array.length());
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA: " + i);
                        Upicks upicks = new Upicks(object.getInt("id_servicio"),
                                object.getString("driver_servicio"),
                                object.getString("inicio_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lat_origen_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lon_origen_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lat_destino_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lon_destino_servicio"),
                                object.getString("cliente_servicio"),
                                object.getString("final_servicio"),
                                object.getString("distancia_servicio"),
                                object.getString("tarifa_servicio"),
                                object.getString("origen_servicio"),
                                object.getString("destino_servicio"),
                                object.getString("estado_servicio"),
                                object.getString("tiempo_servicio")
                        );
                        Log.d("aNTES","EN ONCREATE  4.5 id leido "+object.getString("id_servicio"));
                        MisUpicksFragment.this.upicks.add(upicks);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {


                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("aNTES","EN ONCREATE  5 estouy en getpicks despues de notify");
            }
        };

        asyncTask.execute(id);
    }
```

And this is the button to refresh the items:

```
 botonrefrescar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                getUpicksFromDB(0);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

I am trying to find a solution for two days.

Thank you

EDIT:

```
public class MisUpicksFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";



    private SessionManager session;
    private ProgressDialog loading;
    private EditText txtbusqueda;
    private Button botonbuscar,botonrefrescar;

    //movies
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public List<Upicks> upicks;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayout;
    private UpicksAdapter adapter;


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private String user_id;
    private Button btnNew;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MisUpicksFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MensajesFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MisUpicksFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MisUpicksFragment fragment = new MisUpicksFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        Log.d("MISUPICKS","ESTOE EN MISUPICKS ONCREATE");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_misupicks, container, false);

        txtbusqueda = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtbusqueda);

        botonbuscar =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnbuscar);
        botonrefrescar =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnRefrescar);

        botonbuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String busqueda = txtbusqueda.getText().toString();
                getUpicksBusquedaFromDB(0, busqueda);
            }
        });


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);


        upicks = new ArrayList<>();






        gridLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayout);

        adapter = new UpicksAdapter(getActivity(), upicks);





        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




    Log.d("aNTES","EN ONCREATE 1 ANTES DE CLEAR");
        upicks.clear();
        Log.d("aNTES","EN ONCREATE 2 DESPUES  DE CLEAR");
        getUpicksFromDB(0);
        Log.d("aNTES","EN ONCREATE DESPUES  DE GETUPICKS");

        botonrefrescar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                getUpicksFromDB(0);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
    private void getUpicksBusquedaFromDB(int id, final String busqueda) {



        upicks.clear();



        Log.d("estoy en directorio= ",busqueda);

        Log.d("Texto buscado= ",busqueda);
        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... addressesIds) {

                String URL = "http://.../upicks_todos_busca.php?id="+busqueda;
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(URL)
                        .build();
                try {
                    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    Log.d("Texto buscado=estoy ",busqueda);
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        Log.d("Texto buscado loop= ",busqueda);
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA: " + i);
                        Upicks upicks = new Upicks(object.getInt("id_servicio"),
                                object.getString("driver_servicio"),
                                object.getString("inicio_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lat_origen_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lon_origen_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lat_destino_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lon_destino_servicio"),
                                object.getString("cliente_servicio"),
                                object.getString("final_servicio"),
                                object.getString("distancia_servicio"),
                                object.getString("tarifa_servicio"),
                                object.getString("origen_servicio"),
                                object.getString("destino_servicio"),
                                object.getString("estado_servicio"),
                                object.getString("tiempo_servicio")
                        );

                        MisUpicksFragment.this.upicks.add(upicks);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {


                recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, true);


            }
        };

        asyncTask.execute(id);
    }


    private void getUpicksFromDB(int id) {

        Log.d("aNTES","EN ONCREATE 3 estouy en getpicks antes de clear");
        upicks.clear();
        Log.d("aNTES","EN ONCREATE 4 estouy en getpicks despues de clear");
        Log.d("MISUPICKS","ESTOE EN MISUPICKS getupicksfromddb");

        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... addressesIds) {
                //  Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "UID REGISTRADO ANTES DE CARGAR REECYCLER: " + user_id);



                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://j../upicks_todos.php")
                        .build();
                try {
                    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    Log.d("aNTES","EN ONCREATE  4.5 numero de objetos "+array.length());
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA: " + i);
                        Upicks upicks = new Upicks(object.getInt("id_servicio"),
                                object.getString("driver_servicio"),
                                object.getString("inicio_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lat_origen_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lon_origen_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lat_destino_servicio"),
                                object.getString("lon_destino_servicio"),
                                object.getString("cliente_servicio"),
                                object.getString("final_servicio"),
                                object.getString("distancia_servicio"),
                                object.getString("tarifa_servicio"),
                                object.getString("origen_servicio"),
                                object.getString("destino_servicio"),
                                object.getString("estado_servicio"),
                                object.getString("tiempo_servicio")
                        );
                        Log.d("aNTES","EN ONCREATE  4.5 id leido "+object.getString("id_servicio"));
                        MisUpicksFragment.this.upicks.add(upicks);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

                recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };

        asyncTask.execute(id);
    }


    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);



        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //finish();
    }



    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }


}
```

Comment: I think you need to update your adapter in onPostExecute  method and after update(means you need to reset adapter after get response inside onpostexecute method) call this method adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Dilip, could you be more clear with your proposal?

Comment: When you first time app launch at that time you set adapter same thing you need to do again in onpostexecute method again after setiing adapter call this method adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Dilip, let me try, thank you

Comment: @Dilip, not working. I have updated method as follows:  
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

                recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
               
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                
            }

Comment: No you did again little bit wrong. Missed one more line above of recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); this line updated results comes from onpostexecute method you need to assign to adapter = new ArrayAdapter(parameters);

Comment: Otherwise post your all code of that Activity I will figure out and update.

Comment: @Dilip, I have updated my question including complete fragment code.

Comment: Try this and let me know recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
               adapter = new UpicksAdapter(getActivity(), upicks);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Dilip, no changes, any other idea?

Comment: I am giving reply from mobile so that's why whole answer not able to post some error are coming at time of posting so I will inform step by step you check and update and let me know.first tell me it working fine at first time launch.if it is ok then try this one      
adapter = new UpicksAdapter(getActivity(), upicks); recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, true);  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Dilip, ,not working now at first launch. There is only one row in the database, and gridview shows 2 objects

Comment: @Dilip, I don´t understand anything, It seems to maintain the gridview objects from app launch to app launch

Comment: @Dilip, I will remove the gridview and implement a listview instead,

Comment: No you don't need to maintain such kind of thing in refresh click listener remove all other things except getUpicksFromDB(0); method and add one more thing in getUpicksFromDB method after upicks.clear(); upicks = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159273/discussion-between-mvasco-and-dilip).

Comment: @Dilip, please put yoor proposal as answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If(null != upicks){
    adapter = new UpicksAdapter(getActivity(), upicks);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, true); 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

Comment: thank you, it doesn´t work either, but I want to accept this answer

Comment: Hey@mvasco what is status about that issue.

Comment: Hi, I changed for a simple listview. Thank you